# Python input from the user at runtime which should be passed to MySQLdb

Tags: python

Can someone please explain to me how to get an input at runtime?

Comment: might not be a bad idea to sanitize and use prepared statements, if it's user-supplied data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're asking about getting command line inputs. Once you have that, you should know how to use the inputs however you want like in a MySQLdp.

Try this:
[Pass in a value into Python Class through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765664/pass-in-a-value-into-python-class-through-command-line)

Comment: Thank you for replying me and you answered exactly what I wanted command line inputs.

Comment: Great! Be sure to click the green check! :-)